# How to filter specific keys from nested dictionary

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, dictionary-comprehension

```
dicts = {
        '1': {
            'name': 'hello1',
            'roll': 1,
            'artifacts': ['hello1']
        },
        '2': {
            'name': 'hello2',
            'roll': 2,
            'artifacts': ['hello2']
        },
        '3': {
            'name': 'hello3',
            'roll': 3,
            'artifacts': ['hello3']
        }
    }

keys = ['name', 'roll']
new_dict = {k: {key: v[key]} for k, v in dicts.items() for key in keys}
print(new_dict)
```

Current output:

`{'1': {'roll': 1}, '2': {'roll': 2}, '3': {'roll': 3}}`

I wanted to have the key `name` as well into new_dict.
I am able to do it manually, just trying to do it in pythonic way.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```py
dicts = {
    "1": {"name": "hello1", "roll": 1, "artifacts": ["hello1"]},
    "2": {"name": "hello2", "roll": 2, "artifacts": ["hello2"]},
    "3": {"name": "hello3", "roll": 3, "artifacts": ["hello3"]},
}

keys = ["name", "roll"]

new_dict = {k: {n: v[n] for n in keys} for k, v in dicts.items()}
print(new_dict)
```

Prints:

```py
{
    "1": {"name": "hello1", "roll": 1},
    "2": {"name": "hello2", "roll": 2},
    "3": {"name": "hello3", "roll": 3},
}
```

Comment: Thanks , this works but why it worked?, I also used the loop to iterate the keys but in the end of the comprehension.

Comment: @JohnByro `{k: {key: v[key]} for k, v in dicts.items() for key in keys}` will create `{'1':{'name':'hello1'}}`, then `{'1':{'roll':1}}`. So at the end only the last item stays in the dictionary. (The same with key `'2'`, and `'3'`)

Comment: Thanks , it worked , but i could not use this with dataclasses and dataclass_json